# Laravel: Remove public from url while also keeping projects separate

Tags: php, laravel, directory-structure, organization

This question seems to bother many beginners (like myself) when installing laravel for the first time. We don't want to have the "localhost/public/" in the url and would rather have a clean url. THIS IS NOT A QUESTION ON HOW TO GET RID OF "public" IN THE URL, as there are already many answers to this question.

My question is *"How can I remove the 'public' in the url while also keeping my laravel files in the same directory but also separate from my other projects in my public html/web root folder?"*

## Current wamp www directory File Structure

```
www
|-- mynewlaravelproject
|   |-- laravelfolders(non public folders and files)
|   |-- public
|       |-- index.php (Reached at localhost/public)
|       |-- .htaccess
|-- project1
|-- project2
```

Many solutions are available but it seems that almost all of them have some drawback. Please feel free to correct me on any of the below, as I am asking this question due to a *lack* of understanding.

### 1. Move index.php and .htaccess

Move index.php and .htaccess from public to your laravel project root and remove the public folder all together. *The problem*
    is that now you are forced to include all of laravel in the publicly
    displayed folders of your site, which surely defeats the security
    purpose of separating them right?

```
    www
    |-- mynewlaravelproject
    |   |-- laravelfolders
    |   |-- index.php (Reached at localhost/)
    |   |-- .htaccess
    |-- project1
    |-- project2
```

### 2. Move project files elsewhere, but keep public files in project

Move laravel files to a different non public folder. I moved all of my non-public files into a different directory, leaving the public files behind in the project folder, and then referenced them in my index.php. *The problem* is that now I have to work with all my controllers and models in a separate directory as my public files, this is cumbersome and requires me to have two text editors open.

```
    laravelfiles
    |-- laravelfolders (index.php is referencing bootstrap folder within)
    www
    |-- mynewlaravelproject
    |   |-- index.php (Reached at localhost/)
    |   |-- .htaccess
    |-- project1
    |-- project2
```

### 3. Move laravel folders to just outside your project

The idea behind this is that your project folder in your web root will act as your public folder, and your laravelfolders will sit in the parent web root directory. This one seems the most reasonable, but *the problem* is that now my laravel folders and files are mixed in amongst ALL of my other projects in my wamp web root directory. This is messy and difficult to manage files & folders in a text editor.

```
    www
    |-- mynewlaravelproject(now acts as your public folder)
    |   |-- index.php (Reached at localhost/)
    |   |-- .htaccess
    |-- laravelfolders (This gets messy fast)
    |-- project1 (alongside this...)
    |-- project2 (...and this)
```

### 4. Modify your .htaccess OR use a virtual server

*The problem* is that most people don't recommend modifying your htaccess if at all possible and making a virtual server seems a bit extreme for such a simple task. I don't prefer these options as they seem like workarounds for such a seemingly simple task, I wouldn't be shocked if I'm totally wrong about this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those things are more extreme than using a VirtualHost. This is what virtual hosts are for! You've got one server, and you need it to serve multiple sites from it.  So you map multiple domains to the server using your `hosts` file, then you show a different root folder for each site based on the domain.  So in your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1        myproject.dev
127.0.0.1        myotherproject.dev
```

Apache config file:

```
Listen *:80

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myproject.dev
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myproject/public"
</VirtualHost> 
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myotherproject.dev
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myotherproject/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache and bam! You've got two different laravel projects each with their own domain.  I've got ~10 or so different projects arranged like this on my server and it makes it a cinch to deploy new projects.

Sources: http://www.trailheadinteractive.com/creating_multiple_virtual_sites_a_single_apache_install_windows_xp

Comment: That may be simple for localhost projects, but how does this translate when you are moving your localhost projects to a shared server? Do you have access to the same apache configurations? Sorry, I'm kind of a newb to all of this. Messing with things like "apache config" file make me wonder if the same thing can be done in all different implementations of the site.

Comment: Yep!  The idea of packaged build environments like WAMP is that you can get up and running with windows, apache, mysql, and php very quickly.  But on any server, be it web, local, or otherwise, you'll be using the same tools.  Apache is the same on production or in your home server and operates the same way.  The only difference is instead of using a `hosts` file to point domains at your server, you're using DNS records on the domain.

Comment: Huh, that seems pretty neat. I guess I need to do some more research, but your answer will definitely be one I check out in my search. I will give some time to see what other people have to say.

Comment: Sure is.  I guess I'll clarify one thing, depending on the web host you use (like a virtual private server versus a shared hosting) you may have alternate methods of serving the different folders.  For instance with GoDaddy shared hosting I have on one site, you simply add a domain/subdomain in your admin panel and pick the folder you want to map it to.  It handles the apache stuff.  But regardless of how that works, the folder structure and concept is the same

Comment: I've got to say... thanks for getting me on track. VirtualHost is both an easy and expandable way of separating my different web projects. I can't believe I hadn't learned this yet. Thank you so much.