# How to remove public from the URL of Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, url

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url#28735930) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url#32519877) answers to remove `/public` form the URL of my Laravel project. Now `/public` is removed from the URL. But my IDE (phpstorm) is throwing an error:

[image]

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

**Note:** I use Laravel 5.4

Comment: Both those two other answers you followed are half-truths. They solve the issue by changing the wrong thing. _All_ you need to do is to change the document root in your webserver config. That is all. No other code changes are required. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35640738

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: The links you saw are explaining how to remove `public` from the path if you cannot set the server root to `/public` to begin with. Is that the case with you as well?

Comment: you don't need to edit in your code just follow @aimme answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your apache vhost / host  document root to projects public folder. its realted to apache config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName findexample.com
  DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/find_people/public

  <Directory c:/xampp/htdocs/find_people/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/find-people-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/find-people-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

See [how to setup apache vhost on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658510/1409707)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to touch on any file to get what you want.

Try setting your document root to

```
path/to/your/laravel_app/public/
```

If your root is pointing to your public folder, when you access it from Browser, you will not need to use public in the url.

Remember that you must enable ModRewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `public` from the URL of your Laravel project by following these steps:

1. In your Laravel project's root directory, rename the `server.php` file to `index.php`.
2. Copy the `.htaccess` file from the `public` directory and paste it into the project's root directory.